# install DESeq2 from linux

Tags: r, linux, conda

I am trying to work with DESeq2 from linux but it keep saying there is incompatibility with other libs and with r version.
thank you

i tried with conda as well and in different env but didnt work.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine with Conda:

**deseq2.yaml**

```yaml
name: deseq2
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base=4.2
  
  ## CRAN packages
  - r-tidyverse
  
  ## Bioconductor packages
  - bioconductor-deseq2
```

Add in all the packages you expect to use before creating the environment. Create the environment with

```bash
mamba env create -n deseq2 -f deseq2.yaml
```